# Change default pagination style in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination, wordpress-theming

I am beginner in WordPress and started to learn it. I am designing a new child theme from an existing parent theme. The Pagination of Home page in parent

```
«   Previous   1   2   3   Next   »
```

But I want to modify it like this:

```
Page 1 of 45   1   2   3   NEXT   10    20    30    LAST
```

Following is my code :

```
if (!is_singular()) {
            global $wp_query, $rtp_post_comments;
            if (isset($rtp_post_comments['pagination_show']) && $rtp_post_comments['pagination_show']) {
                if (( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1)) {                    
                        ?>
                    <nav class="wp-pagenavi"><?php
                    echo "<span class='page-count'>Page 1 of " . $wp_query->max_num_pages . "</span>";                    
                    echo paginate_links(array(
                        'base' => str_replace(999999999, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link(999999999))),
                        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
                        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                        'prev_text' => esc_attr($rtp_post_comments['prev_text']),
                        'next_text' => esc_attr($rtp_post_comments['next_text']),
                        'end_size' => $rtp_post_comments['end_size'],
                        'mid_size' => $rtp_post_comments['mid_size']
                    ));
                        ?>
                    </nav><?php
                }
            } elseif (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) {
                wp_pagenavi();
            } elseif (get_next_posts_link() || get_previous_posts_link()) {
                    ?>
                <nav class="navigation clearfix">                                  
                    <?php if (get_next_posts_link()) { ?><div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link(__('Older Entries')); ?></div><?php } ?>
                    <?php if (get_previous_posts_link()) { ?><div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer Entries')); ?></div><?php } ?>
                </nav><?php
            }
        }
```

Where should I change this?

Comment: Looks very complex, maybe this is easier to use: `Page 1 of 45 | 1   2   3   10    20    30    NEXT   LAST`

Comment: @user2019515 : I have modified the code. Plz check it

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [paginate links codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)

paginate_links() is located in wp-includes/general-template.php. (It is not advised to edit the core files.)

Or you can try this plugin: [WP-PageNavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) which will give an option to add "Page 1 of 45" on the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that for some of the custom stuff wordpress functions are less than understandable. But a nice workaround is this:

```
global $page, $numpages;

if ( $numpages > 1 ) : 
                if ( $page == 1 ) {
                    $prev_link = '&nbsp;';
                    $next_link = '<a href="' . get_permalink() . ( $page+1 ) . '">Next Page</a>';
                } else if ( $page == $numpages ) {
                    $prev_link = '<a href="' . get_permalink() . ( $page-1 ) . '">Prev. Page</a>';
                    $next_link = '&nbsp;';
                } else {
                    $prev_link = '<a href="' . get_permalink() . ( $page-1 ) . '">Prev. Page</a>';
                    $next_link = '<a href="' . get_permalink() . ( $page+1 ) . '">Next Page</a>';
                }
            ?>
            <div id="post-pagination">
                <div class="prev-page"><?php echo $prev_link; ?></div>
                <div class="spacer"><?php echo $page.' / '.$numpages; ?></div>
                <div class="next-page"><?php echo $next_link ?></div>
            </div>
```

This is very easy to customize, style AND understand.